# what is the difference between Tailwind and normal CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, visual-web-developer-2010

what is the difference between tailwind and normal css? Can anyone explain I am new to Tailwind css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) is a language used to write rules regarding the style/color/positioning/etc. of elements in an HTML page.

TailwindCSS is a collection of CSS rules, utility classes

Comment: Additionally through TailwindCSS you should not get redundant css styles.

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind is some CSS that someone else has written for you. You use it by writing presentational markup (in the form of class names like `bg-red-100`) instead of writing semantic markup and CSS to apply to it.